# Why page viewer web part is showing error("This content cannot be displayed in a frame") while using external site link in sharepoint 2016 site?

Tags: sharepoint-server, iframe, page-viewer-web-part

Sometimes ago, it was working properly without doing any explicit configurations like the below in our sharepoint2016 site(https://) But now it is failed to display the external site link content (https://) from another domain.

Part of fixing, have done the below things, but still not able to resolve the issue.

i)added this (WebPartPages:AllowFraming runat='server') inside custom master page.
ii)"Permit contributors to insert iframes from any external domain into pages on this site" option is selected under Site Settings > Site Settings > Site Collection Administration > HTML Field Security.

Do we need to do anything else or this feature(displaying iframe is depreciated in sharepoint)..?

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding the below tag into the aspx page which was mapped with the Client Web Part.

```
<WebPartPages:AllowFraming runat="server"/>
```

Source:

[This content cannot be displayed in a frame](https://piyushksingh.com/2016/03/31/this-content-cannot-be-displayed-in-a-frame/)

Or,

```
use <meta http-equiv="X-Frame-Options" content="allow"> in the one to show in the iframe to allow it.
```

Source:

[IFrame: This content cannot be displayed in a frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14141388/iframe-this-content-cannot-be-displayed-in-a-frame)

If the above solution does not fix the issue,  install the **"PermissiveXFrameHeader"** SharePoint solution and enabling the feature for the SharePoint web app. Please refer to this article [Sharepoint: Rendering inside iframes](http://www.sharepointblogs.be/blogs/vandest/archive/tags/Excel%20Services/default.aspx)

Source:

[How to resolve “This content cannot be displayed in a frame” error - CRM 2013 + Sharepoint 2013?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27834148/how-to-resolve-this-content-cannot-be-displayed-in-a-frame-error-crm-2013)

Comment: Thanks for the answer Habibur Rahaman...  Actually in my question i have added this (<WebPartPages:AllowFraming runat="server"/>) which is not published here.                                                      I have installed  "PermissiveXFrameHeader" sharepoint solution  in my webapplication and activated this feature. But,still it is not working..